# Error running pairwise_t_test in R: x data are essentially constant

Tags: r, dplyr, t-test, rstatix

I posted this question a few days ago with no luck, so here we go again:

I am trying to run a posthoc t-test on the following dataset:

```
data.type <- c("DNA","DNA","DNA","DNA","DNA","DNA","DNA","DNA","DNA","DNA","DNA","DNA","DNA","DNA","DNA","DNA","DNA","DNA","DNA","DNA","DNA","RNA","RNA","RNA","RNA","RNA","RNA","RNA","RNA","RNA","RNA","RNA","RNA","RNA","RNA","RNA","RNA","RNA","RNA","RNA","RNA","RNA")
hour <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,24,24,24,48,48,48,96,96,96,168,168,168,672,672,672,1,1,1,2,2,2,24,24,24,48,48,48,96,96,96,168,168,168,672,672,672)
zotu.count <- c(11,14,16,7,16,15,5,14,13,6,5,17,7,7,12,3,4,5,3,5,4,2,3,2,1,6,2,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,4,1,1,1,6,7,6)
id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42)
```

However, I am getting the following error message when I run the code:

```
library(rstatix)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dataset %>% group_by(data.type) %>% pairwise_t_test(zotu.count ~ hour, paired = TRUE, p.adjust.method = "BH")
```

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `data`.
> ℹ `data = map(.data$data, .f, ...)`.
> x data are essentially constant

Does anyone know why this is happening and if so, how to get past it?

Thank you!

Comment: Your code above does not define a data frame called `dataset`. It only has the input vars.

Comment: Yes, in my actual code I did not write "dataset" but the actual name of the file. I only wrote it here to simplify things.